# Why is my post request not creating a new JSON file JS?

Tags: javascript, post, request, fetch

I need to know why my post request isn't creating a new JSON file. I am using a JS POST fetch request. The code is below.

```js
//Assume all the variables are defined
fetch(lowercaseUsernameStr+'_profile_data.json', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 },
 body: {
  "publicData": {
    "username": usernameStr,
    "userDescription": userDescription,
    "favoriteGameData": {
     "favoriteGameCategory": favoriteGameCategoryStr,
     "favoriteGameNum": favoriteGameNum
    },
    "stats": {
     "level": 1,
     "levelXP": 0,
     "maxLevelXP": 100,
     "XPUntilNextLevel": 100,
     "totalXP": 0,
     "trophies": 0
    }
  },
  "privateData": {
   "password": passwordStr,
   "email": email,
   "telNum": telNum,
   "userProfilePageVisibilityYesOrNo":
   optionsSelectedOptionStr,
   "userProfilePictureSrc": userProfilePictureSrc
   }
  }
})
.catch((error)=>{
 alert("Sorry! We could not create your account! Please report the problem and wait until it's fixed! Here is the error: " + error);
 //Assume the local url exists
 document.location = 'contact_and_email_will.html';
});
```

There aren't any easy-to-spot errors for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with _"creating a new JSON file"_?

Comment: I learned that post requests can create new files and add contents to them and put requests can only edit files than already exist.

Comment: @WillTechX20 you learned about a convention, but it doesn't mean that any HTTP server will handle POST/PUT requests like that.

Answer (score 1):

> I learned that post requests can create new files and add contents to them and put requests can only edit files than already exist.

That's not really correct. In a REST API it's convention for a POST request to create new content, and for a PUT request to modify existing content. "Content" here could be files, or database records, or other things.

However, that's only a convention and there's no magic here. There needs to be a server listening that knows what to do. If you want a JSON file created on the server, then you need to write the server side code that listens for a POST request at a specific url and then uses your custom logic to write that JSON file where you want it to be.